# How can I make sure that I don't send any email to customers from testing site in php

Tags: php, mysql, apache, email

I have to make the copy of my existing site for testing purposes at home. I have got the permission from the company.

But in the database I have the more than 10,000 customer records with email.
I don't want to accidentally send any emails to them while i make some mess with site during various tests.

whats the best way to avoid that

I do need the email functionality for testing other stuff

Comment: Simple! Empty the user database keeping only your own (and maybe other devs') email in there

Comment: And additionally, configure the development server to not send mails to "the outside".

Comment: Let me hastily add I do mean the local copy of the database not the production one :)

Comment: If your code is on your local machine, set up a local mailserver with MSMTP or something, then configure your custom mail function to use your local server. Bam. Complete control.

Comment: Or run an update command in your local database to set the email address field to anything. Don't use a `WHERE` clause and all records will be updated at once

Comment: "I do need the email functionality for testing other stuff." - not at the same time as you are testing this, you don't.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most idiot-proof method you can use is often the best for these things as we all have those days where anything that can go wrong will. It's best to be careful, even borderline paranoid, when a mistake could really ruin your day.

Here's a few methods that might work:

**Impotent Configuration by Default**

The absolutely safest system is to keep the SMTP server configuration for the production server on the production server and *only* on the production server. Your development copy would have some other SMTP configuration, like to a testing GMail SMTP account. Usually GMail limits you to 500 emails per day on ordinary accounts so you'll quickly hit this limit if you really screw things up somehow.

**Replace Customer Emails in Database**

Another thing to consider is scrubbing all of the customer emails in your database, removing them and replacing them with `mytestaccount+0000@gmail.com` and `mytestaccount0001@gmail.com` if you care to actually receive and inspect them, taking advantage of the fact that the `+` and subsequent content is ignored for delivery to GMail, effectively giving you unlimited potential email addresses.

As an example:

```
UPDATE customers SET email=CONCAT('mytestaccount+', customer.id, '@gmail.com')
```

You'll have to customize this to be whatever email address you want. One advantage to doing this is that you won't have a valuable list of customer email addresses sitting on your development drive and any associated back-ups of it. To be thorough you should probably scramble the hashed passwords as well just so the database is basically worthless to potential hackers. Too many times passwords get scraped from backups that aren't secured properly.

**Render Customer Emails Undeliverable**

The next best approach is to add ".test" to the end of *every* email in the system you don't want to send so that it will hard bounce instead of going to someone's inbox.

This is basically a one-liner:

```
UPDATE customers SET email=CONCAT(email, '.test')
```

**Over-Ride Email at Delivery Time**

You can always include some conditional logic like where you will deliberately substitute the recipient of the email message. This can be risky because there's a chance that you might disable that switch by accident, though, so as always, be careful.

In practice this looks something like:

```
if ($i_should_not_spam_customer_accounts_accidentally)
{
  $mail->to = "nobody@nowhere"
}
```

**Use an API Driven Service**

Some Mail Service Providers have an API that can help you when testing email messages. I'm a co-founder at [PostageApp](http://postageapp.com/) and the service was designed so you can send messages using an API key that's specifically configured to receive but not deliver emails. Other services like [MailGun](http://mailgun.com/) can be used in a similar fashion.

**No Single Point of Failure**

It isn't a good feeling being one logical test away from tragedy, though. You should make sure there's *several* things that have to go wrong before you have a fiasco.

Comment: Thanks tad that was very good. one more thing , i think there may be some harcoded email addresses written in 100s of php files which i cant find like managers and other distributors. How can i get rid of them . with regex or u have some other idea

Comment: A general email regular expression looks like `/\b(\S+\@\S+\.\w+)\b/` and could be used to search and replace through all of your source files. Just be sure you have everything checked into a version control system so if you mess up your transform you can quickly un-do it, as well as verify what changes you've made. `git` and `perl` are a potent combination here: `perl -pi -e 's/\b(\S+\@\S+\.\w+)\b/nobody@nowhere.nil/g' *` though there are other ways of achieving the same thing.

Comment: This is why putting email addresses in configuration files is always a better idea. It's easy to have a special "development mode" config that sends to test accounts and doesn't annoy your co-workers with confusing "Testy Testerpants" purchase orders.

Comment: thanks buddy , actually that site is managed by 10 different programmers from past 10 years so i can do much about it. its in php4 and home page has html frames in it

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change your code or the data in the database, and if you are using postfix in your local machine, you can rewrite all the outgoing mail to your addres. More info: http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html

Answer (score -6):

Change All the Email Address, For Example `email@domain.com` to `email#domain.com`. After the test completes you can replace `#` with `@`.

Comment: "I do need the email functionality for testing other stuff"

Comment: That implies the OP is solely using `mail()`. Not considering any flexible alternatives that directly communicate via SMTP.